# Certbot, Niginx how to link 3 domains to 1 website also enable https for all

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

I have my server with DigitalOcrean and 3 domains added to my Droplet which hosts my website.

Currently, all 3 domains works fine and point to the 1 website.

I followed this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04): added https support to one 1 domain (wb1.com), but I have 3 domains(wb2.com and wb3.com) for this one site.

How can I enable them all without duplicate the same website folder 3 times under the sites-available folder in Nginx?

There are 2 approaches:

1. enable ssl on all 3 domains and it does not re-direct user to
   wb1.com. The issue is that I have to duplicate the folder for the
   website 3 times;
2. redirect wb2.com and wb3.com to wb1.com

Comment: If you have one website with three domain names, you could create a single certificate with three domain names.

Comment: hi @RichardSmith could you provide more details please? thank you